# Is there a way to send a route to the navigator in a smartphone

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, navigation

We're modeling an Android and iPhone app where we plan to allow the user to plan a route to be traveled on a map. We will then turn this route into a KML or GPX file and send it to the smartphone's navigator. After having googled the subject, however, i find so little information about this that i'm starting to assume this is not something that can not be done. It seems the only thing you can ask the smartphone navigator to do, is to go from point A to point B on the route calculated by the navigator

Can anyone out there confirm this? Also, what would be the reason for this? Do Google want to keep all business in the navigation area to themselves? Are there performance issues? Loading routes into Google maps is possible, so it seems there shouldn't be any technical restrictions.